# When is the set $\{\{x\}: x\in X\}$ locally finite?

Tags: general-topology

In Willard's General Topology, there is an example that says $\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$ is locally finite only under stringent conditions on $X$.

If the above set to be locally finite, we need that each point has an open set containing it and only finitely many other points of $X$. Initially I thought then maybe $X$ must be compact as a result, but this is not true since the topology generated by the sets $\{1,2\}, \{3,4\},\{5,6\},...$  on $\mathbb{N}$ has a finite open set for each $n$ but is not discrete.

What are the 'stringent conditions' on $X$?

Comment: the discrete topology is also a counter when the base set is infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "stringent conditions" are just exactly what you mentioned: the space $X$ must be "locally finite", meaning every point has a finite neighborhood.  There isn't really a more natural way to state the condition than that.

If you want to completely classify such spaces, such a topology on a set $X$ is equivalent to a preorder $\leq$ on $X$ such that for any $x\in X$, the set $\{y\in X:y\leq x\}$ is finite.  The topology corresponding to the preorder then consists of all sets $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\leq x$ imply $y\in U$ for all $x,y\in X$.  Conversely, given a topology, the preorder is defined by $y\leq x$ iff every open set containing $x$ contains $y$.  It is a nice exercise to prove that these correspondences really are inverse to each other.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, for the answer!

Comment: Being a preorder is the same as having a quotient given by an order right?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be as in the problem.

For each element $x\in X$ there is a finite open set $U_x$ containing $x$ such that $U_x$ is contained inside any other open set containing $x$. The family $\{U_x | x\in X\}$ forms a basis of $X$.

This gives us a transitive relation on $X$ where $x\sim y\iff x\in U_y$. It is not hard to see that if $\sim$ is transitive and reflexive, moreover if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim x$ then $U_x$ and $U_y$ are equal. So we can take a quotient of $X$, $Y$ such that $Y$ is the left order topology of an ordered set.